# ScopeConfigInterface as parameter in constructor - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, code-generation

I'm working with Magento 2, I'm still new. I have this constructor inside a controller class:

```
public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
{
  $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
  $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
  return parent::__construct($context);
}
```

It was working until I added the ScopeConfigInterface. Now, when I load my page I get this error:

> Recoverable Error: Argument 3 passed to xxx\Customer\Controller\Login::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface, none given, called in...

Any ideas?... Thanks!

Comment: delete 'var/generation'

Comment: You are right @SohelRana.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted folder:

```
"var/generation"
```

And that solved the problem.